# Write from Spark to Kafka in avro format using defined schema?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-avro

I have a dataframe that I need to write to Kafka.

I have the avro schema defined, similar to this:

```
{
    "namespace": "my.name.space",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MyClass",
    "fields": [
       {"name": "id", "type": "string"},
       {"name": "parameter1", "type": "string"},
       {"name": "parameter2", "type": "string"},
       ...
     ]
}
```

and it's auto-generated to java bean. It's something similar to this:

```
public class MyClass extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  String id;
  String parameter1;
  String parameter2;
  ...
}
```

I found that to write in avro format there is only [to_avro](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro) method that takes a column.

So my question, is there a way to force writing to Kafka in Avro format in this defined schema?

Comment: My understanding is that that is only possible with Confluent Schema Registry.

Comment: did u resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this when using Confluent. See https://aseigneurin.github.io/2018/08/02/kafka-tutorial-4-avro-and-schema-registry.html

Comment: How this is possible with Spark? or you have to write the data manually using foreachPartition?

Comment: I have never tried it, but when I talked to a colleague it was convoluted. He told me they did not have Confluent there due to these type of complications.